# Load fixtures for specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, loading, fixtures

For automated testing, RSpec and FactoryGirl are used.

Frequently, I need to manually play with my application. So, i need a convenient way to populate database with some data.

The most convenient way to do it - is fixtures, because they handling relationships between models very well.

I know, that i can load fixtures via **rake db:fixtures:load command**, but sometimes i need to populate only specific models (say, only customers --> orders --> products)

I'm looking for a command, like this:

```
rake db:fixtures:load --models=customers,orders,products
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

```
rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=customers,orders,products
```

Comment: +1; the only thing that could improve this answer is a link whichever docs say this… (can't find them myself or would edit in)

Comment: I got it from doing `rake -D db:fixtures:load`

Answer (score 1):

What about using the seed command?

```
rake db:seed
```

Here's a railscast explaining it in detail:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data